# Assign values to dropdown option from javascript varaibles?

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown with four option. I want to assign values to dropdown from javascript.

```
                <select class="dropwdown-test" id="dropTest"> 
                    <option>Person 1</option>
                    <option>Person 2</option>
                    <option>Person 3</option>
                    <option>Person 4</option>
                  </select>
```

These are four variables that need to assigned to `option` values from a function() or function(response).

```
                    var p1 = 'john'
                    var p2 = 'marcus'
                    var p3 = 'anthony'
                    var p4 = 'aaron'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {      // on DOM loaded
  var p1 = 'john';
  var p2 = 'marcus';
  var p3 = 'anthony';
  var p4 = 'aaron';
  
  var list = [p1, p2, p3, p4];    // put the variables in a list
  
  var select =  document.getElementById("dropTest");     // get the select
  var options = select.querySelectorAll("option");       // get it's options
  
  options.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if(list[i]) {              // if list has element list[i]
      el.value = list[i];      // assign option value to list[i]
      // commenting out because OP wants only values assigned and not innerHTML
      // el.innerHTML = list[i];  // assign option innerHTML to list[i]
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<select class="dropwdown-test" id="dropTest"> 
  <option>Person 1</option>
  <option>Person 2</option>
  <option>Person 3</option>
  <option>Person 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The dropdown text has changed from `person1` to its value. Can it stay as it is.

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum sure, just remove or comment out either `el.value = list[i];` or `el.innerHTML = list[i];`. Since you want only the value to change and not the text, remove `el.innerHTML = list[i];`.

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum I edited the answer so only values are changed and not the text